# PyQt5 tray icon disappears

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Using PyQt5 5.2 and Python 2.7.6 on Arch Linux with XMonad 0.11 and trayer (or stalonetray).

Wrote up a little demo program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

icon = QtGui.QIcon('clock.png')
tray = QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon(icon)
tray.show()

app.exec_()
```

(clock.png is just some 256x256 icon I found)

If my tray is running, the tray icon shows up fine, though the transparent background seems to be ignored. If the tray gets restarted, which happens from time to time as I recompile XMonad or switch monitor setups, the tray icon disappears and only shows a thin black vertical bar, which I usually can't interact with. The rest of my usual tray icons (Spotify,  Parcellite, nm-applet, Dropbox) display just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Qt 5 (at least until current 5.2.1 stable version) is not friend with most trays under X11. This goes on for quiet some time.

Relevant bug reports:

- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31762
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35658